# php returning file corrupt on mp4 readfile access to folder outside root directory

Tags: php, mp4, readfile

Am trying to load the mp4 file on page but i get a corrupt file message.

Am using this as my php file to load from private folder outside root directory and open it directly from browser to see if video plays directly to firefox browser:

```
if(!empty($_GET['video']))
 {
if (strpos($_GET['video'], "\0") !== FALSE) die('');

$video  = $_REQUEST['video'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($video);
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];

require_once("config.php");

if(isUserLoggedIn())
{ 
    //Construct an Order object
    $IsPaid = new Order($reference=$loggedInUser -> user_id,$pesapal_tracking_id=NULL,$orderstatus = NULL);

    //Check if he is paid
    if($IsPaid->isPaid())
    {

        //Private folder        
                    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../privatelogged/'. $file_name;

        header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate");
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

            set_time_limit(0);
            $resource = @fopen($file,"rb");
            while(!feof($resource))
            {
                print(@fread($resource, 1024*8));
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }

        //readfile($file);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the exact message you are using? Does it come from your code your PHP?

Comment: Comment the content-type and content-length header functions and you should see any errors

Comment: I was not getting any error: and when i comment the the content-type and length i get the following:ftypisomisomiso2avc1mp41freeø¡mdat8ÿÿ4ÜEé½æÙH·–,Ø Ù#îïx264 - core 118 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=dia subme=0 psy=0 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 ... AND So ON..alot of symbols